# Man page aliases

Tags: man

Some man pages document multiple commands/functions in a single page while the man command usually presents the right man page for each one.

Example: the man page for malloc/free/calloc/realloc on many systems

What are the mechanisms man uses for such lookups?

So far I've encountered:

- symlinks under `/usr/share/man/manX`
- alias man pages that just contain a `.so manX/foo` source directive

Of course, thinkable are also hardlinks and copies of man pages.

Are there any other mechanisms supported by man commands?

For example a central index file where such aliases are defined?

Comment: That can be system-dependent (Solaris is a little different from Linux and BSDs).

Comment: @ThomasDickey, that's ok - I'm also interested in an answer that highlights differences between systems.

Answer (score 3):

On OpenBSD, each `man` directory (e.g. `/usr/share/man` for manual relating to the base system) contains a [`mandoc.db`](https://man.openbsd.org/mandoc.db.5) database created by a weekly cron job running [`makewhatis`](https://man.openbsd.org/makewhatis.8).

These databases are created by parsing the various manual sources (roff source files) for particular strings and they are used by the [`man`](https://man.openbsd.org/man.1) utility.  One of the things that is indexed is the strings referred to by the `.Nm` ("name") macro in the `.Sh NAME` section of the manuals typeset using OpenBSD's [`mdoc`](https://man.openbsd.org/mdoc.7) macros.

For example, a part of the very start of the source of the [`malloc(3)`](https://man.openbsd.org/malloc.3) manual in [`/usr/share/man/man3/malloc.3`](https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/src/lib/libc/stdlib/malloc.3?rev=HEAD&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup) looks like this:

```
.Dd $Mdocdate: May 19 2019 $
.Dt MALLOC 3
.Os
.Sh NAME
.Nm malloc ,
.Nm calloc ,
.Nm realloc ,
.Nm free ,
.Nm reallocarray ,
.Nm recallocarray ,
.Nm freezero ,
.Nm aligned_alloc ,
.Nm malloc_conceal ,
.Nm calloc_conceal
.Nd memory allocation and deallocation
.Sh SYNOPSIS
```

The `makewhatis` tool will index each `.Nm` value and the `man` command will show the rendered version of the `malloc.3` source when a user asks for the manual of any of the listed functions (e.g. `man free`).

Manuals not relating to the OpenBSD base system (i.e. 3rd party manuals under `/usr/local/man`) are also parsed by `makewhatis`, but since these often use roff markup that is not `mdoc` (usually written for Linux which uses another macro package), it indexes the values used by other macros (the `.TH` title macro).

Some 3rd party programs seems to distribute a separate manual or for each separate tool or function, even though this means duplicating manuals and just giving them different names.  Using symbolic and/or hard links is also a common solution.

Others are a bit smarter.  This is the complete manual source of `zzip_fread(3)` (part of the `zziplib` package):

```
.so man3/zzip_read.3
```

I.e., it contains a macro that makes the parser read another file.